# Adding new APIs

Tags: api, gmail

Our application has some years of Calendar and Contacts API use, and now we have to add GMail API for sending e-mails. I added it on our console and it say it is enabled, but I can't use it, and I get a message telling the application is blocked (but Calendar and Contacts are going very well). Please, what is missed? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question include [example] as well as any error messages for example where is it saying your app is blocked?  Is your app verified? if so adding a gmail scope is going to either remove that verification or require that you go though the security check for verification probably both.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, y app is verified and it is going well for calendar and contacts. What I cannot understand is if I have to add new scopes and where, and/or if I have to verify it again and how.

Comment: Oh they are defiantly going to unverify it and force you to verify it again if you change scopes.  Remember gmail scopes require a security check by a third party company.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Problem is, I cannot find  where do I have to add new sopes and/or how to ask for a new verification.

Comment: I added an answer for you should show you how to add the new scopes.

Answer (score 0):

In google developer console.  Go to the Oauth consent screen.  Click the edit button at the top, then save and continue.  I think its the third page you come to which allows you to add additional scopes.

Remember there's no going back I really think they are going to unverify your app.

[image]

Please let me know how it goes when you do it.  I am keeping notes on exigence's with the verification process.

Comment: Hello; I tried what you said and was OK, now I am back to verification. Thank you very much!